# WMI + Bitlocker + C# Get encrypted Volumes produces timeout

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

i want to create a wrapper class for specific WMI functions that affect Bitlocker functionality. The first step is to get all the Bitlocker volumes of a machine so I created a Console Application and did this:

```
private static ManagementClass management;
    private static ManagementObjectCollection Volumes = null;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        ManagementPath path = new ManagementPath();
        path.Server = "";
        path.NamespacePath = "\\ROOT\\CIMV2\\Security\\MicrosoftVolumeEncryption";
        path.ClassName = "Win32_EncryptableVolume";


        ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
        options.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy;
        options.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;

        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(path, options);
        ObjectGetOptions getOptions = new ObjectGetOptions();

        management = new ManagementClass(scope, path, getOptions);
        management.Get();
        Volumes = management.GetInstances();

    }
```

When I run this on a non-Bitlocker machine the Volumes Collection gets initialized OK, only that it has a Count of 0 of course. Now I copied the code over to a WinForms App and when I click a button to run this code it steps through OK but when I try to expand the collection during debugging the App hangs and I get a "Function evaluation timed out". It's the same code just in another Application. What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

Hm.  I got a null reference exception if I didn't run it as administrator, but when I ran it as administrator (Win 7 x64, btw), I got four Volumes back.

Comment: Strange thing is, the values are there and I can work with them I just cant see them in debug mode.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar issue, I will post my code for you hopefully it helps.

```
ManagementObjectSearcher Encryption = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"root\cimv2\Security\MicrosoftVolumeEncryption", "SELECT * FROM Win32_EncryptableVolume");

        foreach (ManagementObject QueryObj in Encryption.Get())
        {
            string EncryptionStatus = QueryObj.GetPropertyValue("ProtectionStatus").ToString();

            if (EncryptionStatus == "0")
            {
                EncryptionDialog.Text = "Unencrypted";
            }
            else if (EncryptionStatus == "1")
            {
                EncryptionDialog.Text = "Encrypted - SysPrep will not complete";
            }
            else if (EncryptionStatus == "2")
            {
                EncryptionDialog.Text = "Cannot Determine Encryption";
            }
        }
```

I'm using this to display the status for a sysprep tool i'm creating so the "EncryptionDialog.Text = ..." can be replaced with any other calls you may need. you also need to remember "which caused me issues at least" if you are using visual studio you will need to add a file to your project labeled "Application Manifest File" in the "Add New File" Dialog. The reason for this is that the application will need to be opened in Administrator mode(Just an FYI in case you haven't made it that far)